# GCM push notification Server side for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to .net and using .net as a server side for GCM push notification. I am using the below code and it working fine for single user(for below regId).My question is how to save all reg-id's in our .net server? I don't know whether it save in our server or not.If not saving the registered-id's then how to send push notifications to all registered users?

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                string regId = "APA91bFUgrdgtdgfdgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6t1QDCn-4IiIAtvBhEt328QeYeLKoDeDFOgumrgACdydLCLvM0wM59nAzm_fZse3ta_A";

//server api key
                var applicationID = "AIzaSDGjvbnviiuteuoidsgdfsdryiIfgA";



                var SENDER_ID = "77xxxxxx25";
                var value = Label1.Text;  //message box label
                WebRequest tRequest;
                tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

                // string postData = "{ 'registration_id': [ '" + regId + "' ], 'data': {'message': '" + txtMsg.Text + "'}}";
                string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";
                Console.WriteLine(postData);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

                dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                Label3.Text = sResponseFromServer;
                tReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                tResponse.Close();

            }
```

Now i am getting push notifications in my android device like [this](http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/5599/gcmavdfirstmsg.png) and how to send or get text messages like "hii","test"... rather than "you got tickle".please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a mistake in android side. Finally solved.